# WPF StackPanel has lost its child

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, children, stackpanel

im trying to solve the following problem:

I have a StackPanel that contains an Image as. But if I do panel.Children.Count it sometimes returns 0 and sometimes 1. Why? How can I fix this? 
Note: I get the StackPanel from the sender Object of an MouseEvent.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated:)

Update:

```
private void MoveContainer(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel panel = sender as StackPanel;

    MessageBox.Show(panel.Children.Count.ToString());
}
```

Update 2:

```
<StackPanel Name="a1" AllowDrop="True"
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="StartDrag"
                    PreviewMouseMove="MoveContainer"
                    Visibility="Visible"
                    Background="Transparent">
            <Image Source="testcontainer.png" Width="60" Height="30"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Update 3:

```
private void StartDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    startPos=e.GetPosition(null); //startPos is a local attribute
}
```

Comment: @thedugas updated the code in post :)

Comment: Can you post some of your Xaml, I cannot recreate this issue. It sounds like it might be an event routing issue, is the panel variable always casting correctly?

Comment: @benPearce updated the xaml in the post, yes, its casting correctly. just the number of children is changing between 0 and 1:(

Comment: And what about the code in the StartDrag event handler - can you post that too.

Comment: @benPearce updated it :)

Comment: This question has such a sad title :(

Answer (score 2):

I tested the code and it always returns 1 for me, there is way too few information to know what is wrong on your end though.

In how many places do you modify the StackPanel?
Is that event handler used by other StackPanels which have no children?
Do you use some weird ControlTemplates which cause nested StackPanels?

Comment: i modify the panel just in that method and in another one, but i don't think that the other one is the prob. Yes, I use the same handler for all my stackpanels(some of them have a child others don't) no, no control templates.

Comment: If you use the same handler for other StackPanels, how can you be sure that you always hit the one which actually has a child? You should try and only use the handler for that single StackPanel and see if you still get 0 sometimes.

Comment: but shouldn't the sender object return the panel that has triggered the event? but thanks anyway, i'm going to try it with different handlers.:)

Comment: The sender does return the panel which triggered the event, but what tells you with certainty that the panel that triggered the event is that specific panel with the Image in it? You would need more information about the panel to conclude that. Also: The debugger is there for a reason, it gives you much more information than a message box showing one property of an unknown control.